# Find files and copy with multiple criteria

Tags: python

Hi I got a DF that contains two columns one with invoice number and another with client name.

Is there a way to find all files (by name) that contains "Banana" AND "A5000" at same time?

I've tried to work on a code yesterday and a very nice guy helped me to get trough with one criteria, but I'm stuck again when trying to add another one.

maybe I can't use "and" on this line: `files = list(path.rglob(f'*{v and s}*'))`, i tried "&" but dind't work.

```
data = {'Invoice':['A5000','B8000','C3000'],'Client':['Banana','Orange','Lemon']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)



path = Path('D:/Pyfilesearch')
dest = Path('D:/Dest')



for v,s in zip(df.Invoice,df.Client):
    files = list(path.rglob(f'*{v and s}*'))
    files = [f for f in files if f.is_file()]
    for f in files:
        print(f)
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use sets and intersection, as in the following example:

```
p = Path("files")

data = {'Invoice':['A5000','B8000','C3000'],'Client':['Banana','Orange','Lemon']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

for i, c in zip(df.Invoice, df.Client):
    s1 = set(p.rglob(f"*{i}*"))
    s2 = set(p.rglob(f"*{c}*"))
    i_c_files = s1.intersection(s2)
    print(i_c_files)
    if i_c_files:
        first_file = list(i_c_files)[0]
        print("the first file is " + str(first_file))
```

Comment: Hi clever solution, it return the correct path, but when i try to shutil it throw me an exception: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not set

Comment: Updated the solution a bit, to include the loop in your code. Have a look,

Answer (score 1):

Use substring in file.stem

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

data = {'Invoice':['A5000','B8000','C3000'],'Client':['Banana','Orange','Lemon']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

path = Path('D:/Pyfilesearch')
for v, s in zip(df.Invoice,df.Client):
    files = [f for f in path.iterdir()
                if f.is_file() and v in f.stem and s in f.stem]
    for f in files:
        print(str(f))
"""
D:\Pyfilesearch\A5000 Banana.txt
D:\Pyfilesearch\B8000 Orange.txt
D:\Pyfilesearch\C3000 Lemon.txt
"""
```

Comment: Hi ty for answer, but it dind't work, it print nothing.

Comment: I created the directory Pyfilesearch and have 9 files, then add some statements to make executable, then it do  work. Update as above.

Comment: You are correct, my file was on a sub directory inside of D:\Pyfileseach\, sorry about that.

changed to path.glob('**/*'), now it worked fine, srry again!